# Chartjs axis description is not selectable and therefor not copyable

Tags: chart.js

the axis description are not selectable and therefor not copyable. Is there a way to make them selectable and copyable?

For example like "value" or "January "in the following example.
https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/line-styles.html

Answer (score 0):

No.

The [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) element renders as a bitmap, similar to a JPEG or PNG.

If selecting text is a requirement for you then use a SVG-based charting library.